# Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address # to the list of known hosts

Tags: git

When I tried to do a `git push` I got this:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '###.##.###.###' to the list of known hosts.
>   ERROR: Repository not found.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists`

What does it mean? Should I be worry?

Answer (score 5):

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '###.##.###.###' to the list of known hosts.

This is normal if it is the first time you try push to the server, It is part of the ssh handshake and stores the fingerprint of the remote server ssh key for future validation.

> ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

This may happen if you have the wrong url to your remote repo.

Run `git remote -v` and check that you have the right urls to your remote repo

Comment: I was facing the same issue when i was trying to clone the repository, i just forked. What i did is changed the clone URL From SSH to HTTP that worked from me. May b that can help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure the address you filled in is correct,you can use `git remote -v` command to display configuration information

2.When I first pushed the code to the new repository on github, I forgot to use the `git add` /`git commit -m` command to directly use the `git push` command, then display that warning